# How to connect AWS RDS (private subnet) to Microsoft Power BI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a database cluster (Aurora MySQL) within a private subnet. One of the databases has been migrated from DigitalOcean. I want that database to connect to Microsoft Power BI I built. How do I achieve that? Previously, I used to install the on-premises data gateway (personal mode) which conects to the dashboard (app.powerbi.com).

Although Bastion EC2 tunneling is successful - via PuTTy - how to connect to the database?

I have tried:

1. Install MySQL Workbench and setup SSH tunneling (provide EC2 and RDS information) but Power BI connection failed
2. Create a new data source via app.powerbi.com (PostgreSQL or MySQL) but Power BI connection failed
3. Perform SSH tunneling via PuTTy but Power BI connection failed